# Is there a way to keep Table and Matrix visuals from resetting to the top when changing Pages in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

Power BI: Is there a way to prevent Table and Matrix visuals from scrolling to the top when selecting a Page?

I scroll a table to get to a certain row of data, then select another Page to look at another section of the data. When I switch back to the first Page the table has scrolled to the top. Is there a way to prevent this automatic scrolling?